# Replicate an HttpPost request from fiddler with android

Tags: android, json, wcf, http-post

I've built a wcf service using json.I think it works ok since i've been debugging it with fiddler.I can't though call it correctly from android.I think i must be doing something wrong when trying to pass the parameters.This is the fiddler request:

**Request Headers:**

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: androidwcf.schoolportal.gr
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 73

**Request Body:**

{
    "ID":2147483647,
    "description":"String content",
    "enable":true
}

how can i pass this json object as a parameter with android?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as ti to Post current json obejct to your server :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

    String http = "YOUR_WEB_URL";  
    //System.out.println("-----------------" + http+"?"+param);  
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;  
    try {  
        URL url = new URL(http);  
         urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url  
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);   
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Fiddler");  
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);  
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","73");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "androidwcf.schoolportal.gr");
        urlConnection.connect();  

         //Create JSONObject here
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
        jsonParam.put("description", "String content");
        jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonParam.toString());
        out.close();  

        int HttpResult =urlConnection.getResponseCode();  
        if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
                    urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                sb.append(line + "\n");  
            }  
            br.close();  

                System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

        }else{  
            log.warn(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());  
        }  
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    catch (IOException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();  
    }finally{  
        if(urlConnection!=null)  
           urlConnection.disconnect();  
    }  

}
```

Comment: why did you use xmlSerializer?isn't just a JSON object?

Comment: then try it with out using it this is small change dear important    is it's working or not ?

Comment: oh ok i'll try it and back to you

Comment: in this command:         out.write(jsonParam.toJson(newClient));
what is the 'newClient'?